# Swift 4 JSON Decodable from Hacker News API not in correct order?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have made the request and I am getting the data and it's all working fine in my tableView but the articles seem to not be in perfect order. Some ARE in the correct order, but others are not...

API: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?

Matches real site:
    https://news.ycombinator.com/

I compared the IDs from my response to the ones from the real JSON and they match, so that's not the issue. Is it because some of the requests are finishing before others? If so, how should I refactor my code to call them in the correct order?

```
private func getTopStoriesArray() {
    guard let url = URL(string: topStoriesURLString) else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let data = data else { return }

        if let topArticlesArray = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: data) {
            let chunk = topArticlesArray.chunked(by: 100) // 500 articles are received from API
                _ = chunk[0].map { self.getArticle(id: String($0)) }
        }
    }.resume()
}

private func getArticle(id: String) {
    let articleId = id
    guard let url = URL(string: "\(articleURLBase)\(articleId).json") else { return }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            let json = try JSONDecoder().decode(Article.self, from: data)

            let author = json.by ?? "author"
            let comments = json.descendants ?? 0
            let kids: [Int] = json.kids ?? []
            let score = json.score ?? 0
            let time = json.time ?? 0
            let type = json.type ?? "type"
            let url = json.url ?? "url"

            // Create new article from JSON
            let article = Article(by: author, descendants: comments, id: json.id, kids: kids, score: score, time: time, title: json.title, type: type, url: url)
                // Add article to data source for tableview
                self.articles.append(article)
                // Jump to main thread and reload tableview
                self.hackerTableView.performSelector(onMainThread: #selector(self.reloadData), with: nil, waitUntilDone: true)
        } catch {
            print("error with getting article")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

I'm assuming me calling the `getArticle()` function on each article id is the problem as they don't return one after the other in perfect order?

Comment: The code you're using to parse the array of article IDs is a truly horrible hack. Why not just JSONSerialization? That will convert it to an array in 1 step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing async calls to fetch the articles. There is no guarantee as to what order those will complete. They may tend to complete in order, or maybe not. You should not assume that they will.

You need a data structure that preserves your order. You could save an array of article IDs, and then create a dictionary where the key is the article ID and the value is the content of the article.

To populate your table view you'd look up the article ID in the array of article IDs at the specified row, then use that article ID to fetch the article from your dictionary of articles.

Calling `reloadData` on the table view for every article is a bad idea performance-wise. You should instead look for the article ID in your array of article IDs, then tell the view controller that manages the table view to update that index. In the view controller, use `reloadRows(at:with:)` to tell the table view to reload the cells who's data has just been reloaded. That will prevent you from re-rendering the whole table view for each cell.

### EDIT:

As mentioned in my comment, your code to decode the array is a mess. It's JSON data, so you could either use the older `JSONSerialization` style, or the new `JSONDecoder` class added in Swift 4. That code would look like this:

```
let jsonString = """
[16249058,16248449,16249048,16246805,16232898,16248247,16245216,16247254,16248747,16246432,16245817,16247964,16238367,16220646,16248660,16248782,16246485,16243067,16245773,16245873,16247109,16248704,16248860,16235983,16237655,16246093,16247577,16245108,16242380,16246807,16220298,16242908,16246531,16247165,16246691,16246690,16243306,16247667,16246297,16245606,16221166,16246817,16247921,16247847,16247093,16245697,16247958,16242336,16248889,16248587,16248866,16244298,16246544,16240587,16238937,16248810,16248079,16240234,16244835,16245284,16246424,16236832,16246906,16240911,16243784,16243795,16244564,16244175,16241454,16243539,16248336,16243506,16230933,16246227,16243207,16244580,16243276,16239822,16240644,16245142,16246929,16247474,16242506,16235044,16244827,16245034,16241007,16244194,16243127,16238806,16246203,16243700,16246003,16239446,16242955,16244668,16218439,16240874,16242383,16237558,16225455,16234213,16242060,16230464,16245665,16245586,16234060,16241659,16242037,16232480,16240345,16239839,16235634,16245229,16237854,16237462,16240656,16247776,16242624,16224427,16237609,16235899,16241024,16241294,16222478,16233644,16243223,16241524,16232946,16242293,16247409,16238501,16241226,16235417,16246021,16244010,16245807,16239389,16221661,16246497,16228138,16227009,16245725,16227636,16240183,16240871,16246615,16233859,16233325,16238465,16237227,16233953,16239843,16245932,16220017,16230541,16237509,16241570,16242826,16222520,16246890,16241208,16226923,16232509,16233578,16245077,16236104,16242925,16216960,16222342,16245736,16225531,16218872,16238535,16239594,16234067,16227139,16235062,16238796,16236397,16237026,16240485,16239992,16238322,16237437,16236692,16242855,16219251,16240772,16225386,16223929,16237920,16240036,16232511,16234057,16226457,16225826,16235873,16233903,16225359,16237100,16245204,16237568,16243841,16232194,16240389,16223778,16230937,16239006,16244522,16224988,16233336,16248186,16218949,16244881,16238595,16226746,16235588,16224346,16230854,16229927,16245707,16227969,16226800,16223830,16224006,16225590,16219947,16238379,16215130,16228048,16242455,16233330,16223537,16224209,16219153,16226830,16221579,16244994,16225832,16218393,16232863,16230476,16230067,16226928,16242090,16236268,16236533,16216647,16245330,16233898,16229539,16223278,16217339,16223651,16238416,16218986,16226303,16225532,16233222,16234419,16220709,16219547,16231300,16243079,16225692,16232378,16218333,16229619,16215960,16238720,16225918,16221755,16230810,16215788,16243875,16226429,16245411,16219570,16244350,16244908,16229541,16220299,16241376,16216612,16224367,16221924,16242066,16226010,16226521,16221188,16244039,16218693,16233961,16238522,16226251,16223921,16219395,16216065,16230842,16226870,16234632,16225638,16220267,16230944,16227596,16236416,16232258,16232018,16243100,16242978,16231937,16235842,16244968,16242917,16228788,16232758,16222530,16226495,16229720,16242773,16227130,16220376,16242384,16231418,16227513,16235443,16228029,16215363,16221836,16226294,16238619,16239543,16231806,16235519,16220666,16243097,16227520,16218084,16241684,16236214,16225854,16245383,16242475,16216329,16244235,16229257,16238461,16235404,16241923,16238143,16231909,16234901,16224849,16223597,16231440,16223432,16224238,16237940,16245642,16236593,16232905,16245198,16236468,16226235,16227276,16222537,16233368,16236053,16231456,16235160,16216524,16227745,16234208,16230910,16235460,16242954,16221563,16221771,16217241,16229615,16237090,16239010,16224725,16222715,16229268,16242236,16238891,16242146,16223973,16223936,16235886,16243498,16215328,16246409,16225233,16232577,16234520,16229828,16218976,16230337,16220262,16235849,16235823,16228317,16228160,16236404,16234734,16236778,16235436,16240006,16226835,16226802,16232410,16228615,16216187,16217419,16236359,16215555,16219892,16236108,16235864,16224226,16235391,16238667,16231129,16235520,16238464,16236738,16238279,16231658,16232940,16221132,16224165,16234228,16221177,16237803,16220271,16231324,16222279,16235007,16219758,16231863,16220638,16222280,16220514,16234088,16234043,16216789,16234550,16221850,16230607,16217101,16228215,16232337,16232253,16228154,16228147,16224059,16236123,16225857,16236083,16236345,16226387,16235046,16226091,16235412,16216763,16235122,16234808,16224852,16234774,16218637,16218427,16223902,16227559,16219584,16233945,16233942,16233939,16233850,16227163,16221053,16233457,16226590,16227475,16225383,16232659,16225905,16225830,16232406,16228740,16231575,16215764,16228327,16238251,16218971,16223392,16230666,16218488]
"""
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)
if let array = try? decoder.decode(Array<Int>.self, from: data) {
  //Your code to use the array goes here
}
```

Comment: `data(using: .utf8)` will never return nil. You can simply force unwrap the result or use `Data(jsonString.utf8)` which returns non optional data

Comment: I try to avoid force-unwrapping whenever possible, especially in a forum post. I do like your suggestion of using `Data(jsonString.utf8)` since that will map the string to UTF8 in a way that can't fail.

Comment: Apple do use the force unwrap. check this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder

Comment: I've seen lots of questionable code in Apple's samples. Our company builds with SwiftLint, and it's set up to flag all force-unwraps as warnings. I don't like cluttering up my code with warnings, so I just avoid force-unwrapping if at all possible.

Comment: And I especially try to avoid force-unwrapping in code that may be consumed by newbies, since they tend to overuse it, to disastrous effect.

Comment: I don't use the force unwrap but again Swift Strings are utf8. It can't fail. If you are concerned about the force unwrap warning just use the Data initializer. `let json = Data("""
[16249058,16248449,16249048,16246805]""".utf8)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I guess I'll try your suggestion and make a dictionary. I'm still a bit confused because my array of IDs is in order when I get it from the network? Anyways, I fixed up my bugged code and yes, I know calling reloadData is not good for performance so I'll address that as well thank you.

Comment: Yes, the array of IDs is in order when you read it. Then you make a whole bunch of async calls to fetch the Article objects. It's like you had a bunch of helpers and you give each of them a single Dewey Decimal number of a book to go check out at the library. Each helper drives to the library through traffic, waits in line, gets a book, and brings it back. Sometimes a helper gets stuck in line and takes a little longer. Sometimes a helper makes all the lights and has no lines, so gets back really soon.

Comment: Even though you send them out one at a time in order, they take varying amounts of time to fetch their book, so they don't all come back in order. Async network tasks are very much like that.

Comment: got it working with your suggestions. Thanks for the explanation. I was excited when I figured it out and I learned a lot about completion handlers!

Answer (score -2):

Please check this relevant tutorial, I have tried to add all the required things for Hacker news api,

https://github.com/ansh7jain/HackerNews-Firebase

I have covered. 
1. Shown 50 stories of hacker-news.
2. Store the stories in local DB and shown the entries offline.
3. Fetch next 50 records on pull to refresh from bottom.
4. Shown the news based on sorted score, ascending order.
5. Maintain the read/Unread status of news.